# Spin-Dependent Interaction Terms in SM Lagrangian

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, interactions, beyond-the-standard-model

I was wondering whether there is an intuitive reason why in the standard model (SM) there are no spin-dependent interaction terms, which instead appear in other theories.

Comment: Can you give an example of "spin-dependent interaction term from other theories"?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_decomposition#Utility, there are spin-dependent terms but they are hidden.